# Structure of subresources schema in Python Eve

Tags: python, eve

I could not figure out how subresources work in Python EVE.
I tried this:

```
DOMAIN = {
    'people':{
        'type': 'dict',
        'required': False,
        'schema':{
            'name':{
                'type':'string',
                'required':True
            },
            'id':{
                'type':'string',
                'required':True
            },
            'books':{
                'type': 'dict',
                "url": "people/<regex('[a-f0-9]{24}'):people_id>/books",
                'schema':{
                    'name':{
                        'type':'string',
                        'required':False
                    },
                    'id':{
                        'type':'string',
                        'required':False
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I do a POST to URL: 
    http://127.0.0.1:5000/people/58f5527d211d561ea1b35d8b/

With Input:
    {
        'bookname':'something',
        'bookid':'1001'
    }

I get **"The method is not allowed for the requested URL.**, But I have 
RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET' , 'DELETE', 'POST']
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE']
allowed.

I know I am missing the correct way of POST-ing subresources and I could not find any documentation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the eve demo settings file, there's a [simple sub-document](https://github.com/pyeve/eve-demo/blob/master/settings.py#L85) defined in there:

```
'schema': {
    'firstname': {
        'type': 'string',
        'minlength': 1,
        'maxlength': 10,
    },
    'lastname': {
        'type': 'string',
        'minlength': 1,
        'maxlength': 15,
        'required': True,
        'unique': True,
    },
    'role': {
        'type': 'list',
        'allowed': ["author", "contributor", "copy"],
    },
    # An embedded 'strongly-typed' dictionary.
    'location': {
        'type': 'dict',
        'schema': {
            'address': {'type': 'string'},
            'city': {'type': 'string'}
        },
    },
    'born': {
        'type': 'datetime',
    },
}
```

So, looking back at your snippet, I would say that you miss a `'type': 'dict'` definition for your "books" field.

Comment: is there some documentation where I could find the endpoint mapping to subresources? I could not find any. Thanks

Comment: Can you modify the answer to show much more complicated schema: dict(list(dict)).